# how to append query parameters on URL for all the child roots in typescript

Tags: typescript, query-string

I have a requirement like read particular key from the Url which user enters
for example
EX : localhost:4200/?tenantId=Demo

I have to read tenantId from the url then it redirects to some third party library and comes back to localhost(Integration with third party library). When user clicks on one of my left menu item, url changes like "localhost:4200/insights"

My routes.ts look likes below

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: PagesComponent,
        canActivate : [AppAuthGuard],
        data: { roles: ['Developer', 'Tester'] },

        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: './insight/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'insight',
                loadChildren: './insight/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'eis',
                loadChildren: './eis/eis.module#EisModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'oce',
                loadChildren: './oce/oce.module#OceModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'analytics',
                loadChildren: './clm/clm.module#ClmModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'automation',
                loadChildren: './sa/sa.module#SaModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'builder',
                loadChildren: '../common/theme-builder/builder.module#BuilderModule'
            },
            {
                path: 'profile',
                component: ProfileComponent
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        canActivate: [NgxPermissionsGuard],
        loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule',
        data: {
            permissions: {
                except: 'ADMIN'
            }
        },
    },
    {
        path: '404',
        component: ErrorPageComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'error/:type',
        component: ErrorPageComponent
    },
];
```

My url should look like localhost:4200/insight?tenantId=Demo

How can I achieve?

Comment: Show 'route' in 'dashboard.module.ts' please!

Comment: Thanks for help, I solved this problem by adding query params  in html. 
[routerLink]="[item.page]" [queryParams]="{tenantId: cookieService.get('tenantId')}"